# Catching card button click with Activity.Text null

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have created a new card. Which should get caught when the user clicks the button.

```
 var card = new HeroCard
                {
                    Title = "Welcome ",
                    Text = "Click the buttons below to update this card",
                    Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                    {
                        new CardAction
                        {
                            Type= ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                            Title = "Update Card",
                            Text = "UpdateCardAction",
                            DisplayText = "UpdateCardAction",
                            Value =  new JObject { { "count", 0 } }
                        },
                        new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Get an overview", null, "Get an overview", "Get an overview", "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0"),

                    }
                };

                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment()));
```

## Method to check button

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            turnContext.Activity.RemoveRecipientMention();

            switch (turnContext.Activity.Text.Trim())
            {

             ................
```

## issue

how ever its not catching becouse turnContext.Activity.Text is null all the time when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using **ActionTypes.MessageBack** it seems that we can not get the **Text** property

- To get the **value**, you can access it by going to **turnContext.Activity.Value** which in this case it will be the **JObject { { "count", 0 } }**
- If you wish to get the **DisplayText** you can do the following

  `var channelData = JObject.FromObject(turnContext.Activity.ChannelData);
   var displayText = channelData["messageBack"]["displayText"].ToString();`